# Is the montage in Casa Bonita all the times Cartman called Kyle a Jew up to that point?

Tags: south-park

In Season 7, Episode 11 (Casa Bonita) Cartman asks Kyle "When have I ever ripped on you for being a Jew?" to which there is a montage of maybe 15 of the times Cartman 'ripped on Kyle for being Jewish.'

That isn't the grand total of times that Cartman called Kyle a jew in the first seven seasons is it?

The [script](https://southpark.fandom.com/wiki/Casa_Bonita/Script) makes it sound like it could be by stating that Cartman 'thinks back and counts the number of times Cartman has ripped on him for being a Jew' but I am curious if anyone knows for sure.

Answer (score 1):

That is most certainly not the grand total. Considering there is an average of 16 episodes per season, with cartman calling Kyle a jew atleast once per episode. 15 is just too little,

The Fandom script is simply a transcript fans have made and not the official script, thus a bit of salt must be taken with it.

That particular list is likely the ‚best of‘ the writers liked the most or decided to use for whatever reason, since many of his jew calling is a quick one off statements. If i get bored perhaps i will go through to count all of them.

Comment: That was my thought as well, but I don't have the time to go back and prove it to myself and I was hoping the internet could help...